Easiest way to represent edits to a submodule of a submodule?
I am using a submodule "A" that relies on it's own submodule "B", to which I needed to make a single tiny change (like, 1 line). I'd like to get this change represented in my repository. As I see it, the options are:

Make 2 forks: Fork B with the edit, then fork A where the only change is changing the submodules.
Make some script in my repository that applies the edit with just a basic file replacement, maybe running during the build process.
Use git patches somehow, I've heard of it but never used it.

What would be the cleanest way to do this? I wanted to avoid making and dealing with forks that basically don't do anything - seemed like a waste.
I haven't tried the git patches yet.

If you are not contributor of that submodules, first approach is a good way.

If yes, just edit submodules, you can work with them like with regular repositories, ie cd, edit, commit, push.
